# Appfabric cache ErrorCode<ERRCA0016>:SubStatus<ES0001>

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var config = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration()
        {

            Servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> 
            {
                new DataCacheServerEndpoint("192.168.129.118", 22233)
            }
            ,
            TransportProperties = new DataCacheTransportProperties()
            {
                ConnectionBufferSize = 99999,
                ChannelInitializationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 99999,
                MaxBufferSize = 99999,
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            },
            SecurityProperties = new DataCacheSecurity(DataCacheSecurityMode.Transport, DataCacheProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign),

        };

        DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory(config);
        var cache = factory.GetCache("Maestro_del_mambo");
        cache.Put("123", "que tal andamios");
        var cities = cache.Get("123");
        Console.Read();
      }
```

When executing it it fails on the cache.put and cache.get with the following error message:

> ErrorCode<ERRCA0016>:SubStatus<ES0001>:The connection was terminated,
>   possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than
>   MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is unknown.

The server side cache cluster has granted my client account so.... What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful piece [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/11/03/appfabric-cache-cache-servers-and-cache-clients-on-different-domains.aspx) on the AppFabric blog that talks about this error with some diagnosis and workarounds which might be helpful for you, particularly as you reference your cache server by IP address and not name.

Comment: It's not working, we have our PC's in different domains, so we cannot add the  client pc in the server. What can we do to solve it?